# Using @font-face and fonts from fontsquirrel

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

I am trying to create my first website and I am experimenting with fonts from fontsquirrel.

The only problem is that I can use only SOME of the fonts I have downloaded through the site.

I am having a great deal of a problem in particular in writing the css code correctly, when the font family includes MORE THAN ONE STYLES.

Lets take for example the LM Mono 10 Regular and Special Elite for example:

My code for special elite is the following and it works great:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'specialelite';
src: url('specialelite.eot');
src: url('specialelite.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('specialelite.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('specialelite.woff') format('woff'),
     url(' specialelite.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url(' specialelite.svg# specialelite') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;                }

AND

.fifth {font-family: 'specialelite'; font-weight: normal; font-size: 16px; color:black;}
```

BUT.. When I am trying to adapt this format on any style of the LM Mono 10 family, it simply does not work....

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latin-Modern-Mono

I am trying for two days and several hours now and I am on the brink of a narvous crisis... I do not know if the mistake is on the way I am referring to the font family, or if I write the urls wrong... PLEASE, I REALLY BEG YOU, CAN YOU provide an example of the code in a reply?

Let's say for "Latin Modern Mono Light 10 Regular"..

I just don't get it..

Thank you in advance,

Alexandros.

Comment: The code you posted is valid however I wonder whether you have actually copied the font files to the same location as the CSS otherwise it won't see it

Comment: Yes, the files are in the same location.. I am still trying to find a way to make the LMMono to appear... I just cannot get it.

Comment: I m trying @font-face {
    font-family: 'LMMono10LightRegular';
    src: url('LMMono10LightRegular.otf');
    src: url('LMMono10LightRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('LMMono10LightRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('LMMono10LightRegular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('LMMono10LightRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('LMMono10LightRegular.svg#LMMono10LightRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: regular;
    font-style: light;

}

Comment: Hmmm I'll have a look for an example for you

Comment: Add this to the css for the doc your using tell me if anything happens 
   body{
   font-family: 'LMMono10LightRegular';
   }

Comment: You think? but why would that make a difference? I ll try it first thing in the morning, I m off to bed.. tyD

Comment: I just want to see if that changes any elements for you see if it makes an impact

Comment: Still the same, no difference. I just do not get it. I have the same issue with a couple others fonts also. disgusting...

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to get your font working have a look at my code I put all the files in the root of the HTML called

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Font Test</title>


  <style>
  @font-face{ 
 font-family: 'MyWebFont';
 src: url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.eot');
 src: url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
      url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('lmmono10-regular-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
 }

 p { font-family: 'MyWebFont'; }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<p>My Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: That was helpful in that I ve learned that it really does not matter how you name your font family, but.. it still does not work. Its madness.

Comment: maybe the fact that I am using bootstrap is affecting some fonts??

Comment: I've just put the latest bootstrap CDN in the above and it did not make a difference edit you question with the directory structure and code and I'll have a look

Comment: Or send me the website address and I'll have a look